# local movement on rigidbody sphere with the mouse and keyboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, geometry

So i have completed the Roll a ball tutorial from Unity that is a little game that uses a sphere with a rigidbody applied to it with some basic movement script found [here](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-a-ball).

What i want now is to take it a step further and introduce a somewhat more advanced movement script which also takes mouse input into play.

What i am trying to achieve is so to add force based on the local axis, so if i i move the mouse left the ball turns and the force is added in that direction. Let me show what code i have come up with (added to a simple sphere with rigidbody applied):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float turnSpeed = 2.0f;
    public float moveSpeed = 250.0f;

    void FixedUpdate() {

        float h = turnSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        transform.Rotate(0, h, 0);

        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rigidbody.AddForce(movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

}
```

Ok so what is happening is that the ball is turning when i move the mouse, and the ball is rolling if i use the arrowkeys, but what i'm not managing to figure out after some trial and error is to get the ball moving in the direction it is turning.

How would you approach this particular scenario? Any help is as always much appreciated guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around this and sharing for others to see.

I reference to the camera GameObject and use the camera.transform on the keys. Guess it is really basic but still.

```
public GameObject Camera;
public float moveSpeed = 0.0f;

if (Input.GetKey ("right") || Input.GetKey ("d")) {
    rigidbody.AddForce( Camera.transform.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

if (Input.GetKey ("left") || Input.GetKey ("a")) {
    rigidbody.AddForce( -Camera.transform.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

if (Input.GetKey ("up") || Input.GetKey ("w")) {
    rigidbody.AddForce( Camera.transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

if (Input.GetKey ("down") || Input.GetKey ("s")) {
    rigidbody.AddForce( -Camera.transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something Like this should do the trick::

```
if (Input.GetKey ("up") || Input.GetKey ("w")) {
    rigidbody.AddForce( Camera.transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(vector3.right * speed)
    //Note that rotation happens around the axis, so when moving (forward orback you will rotate on the vector3.right/left) and when moving( Right/left you will use the vector3.forward/back)
}
```